# JetBrains Rider EAP on Linux - Solution load failed: MsBuild not found

Tags: msbuild, jetbrains-ide, rider, failed-to-load-viewstate

Just installed the latest version of Rider EAP (163.12057) and tried to create a new solution.

In my Solution Explorer its shows my Solution and *(load failed)*.
In the Event Log window I get the error message:

> Solution 'FirstSolution' load failed: MsBuild not found on this machine

Any ideas on how I can solve this loading problem?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What OS are you use (Ubuntu CentOS etc)?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I managed to solve the loading error.

I was missing Mono and found out through this thread [here](https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207243685-Unity3D-support?page=2#comments) that Rider currently needs Mono 4.6.2.

I followed [this](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/#usage) guide to install Mono.

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install mono-devel
sudo apt-get install mono-complete
```

I hope this will help someone else.

UPDATE: Asp.Net Core

if you'll be using Asp.Net Core, and encounter error about missing `xsp.exe` you might need to install `mono-xsp4` with this command

`sudo apt-get install mono-xsp4`

Comment: thank you! It's just seems weird at first because I checked the mono lib has the xsp4.exe file linked to an xsp binary in its gac folder.

Answer (score 3):

Accepted answer led me to the official guide: [Mono-project download](https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/#download-lin)

This can help with various other systems (different than Debian). It helped me to get through the process and resolved problem on Ubuntu 18.04.

For Ubuntu 18.04 it is, first `Add the Mono repository to your system`:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
echo "deb https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-bionic main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official-stable.list
sudo apt update
```

then,

```
sudo apt install mono-devel
sudo apt install mono-complete
```

Comment: Best to quote the relevant bits for the specific question.

Answer (score 1):

For Arch Linux and derivatives you'll need:

```
sudo pacman -S mono mono-tools msbuild
```

Invalidate caches & Restart on Jetbrains to apply